# Excel multiple criteria by row

Tags: excel, count, row, multiple-columns

I am having trouble with Excel. I have a data set containing bibliography. For each row I have each author from a specific title, separated by columns. I wanted to make an association between authors to see which have publications together and how many times.

Example of data set:

[image]

[full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biaJc.png)

Output wanted:

[image]

[full view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2gUr.png)

I have approximately 43 columns by 500 rows. I've already tried `COUNTIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT` but both don't give me the output that I want.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What were the formulas you used? It looks like you just need to combine the names in a list, remove duplicates, copy/transpose then do a `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: I think maybe there are too many columns for Countifs to be practicable, will need an array formula.

Comment: Already tried COUNTIFS() and SUMPRODUCT(), but didn't obtained the expected output

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way than this, but with 43 columns (a lot of co-authors?) I can only think of using an  array formula, so the method is:-

(1) Get row totals of original data for first author

(2) Get row totals of second author

(3) Multiply them together to get rows (publications) where both authors occur.

(4) Optional - check that each row total is greater than zero -shouldn't be necessary unless author's name is repeated.

(5) Add them all up.

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(N($A$2:$D$20=G$1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1))^0)*MMULT(N($A$2:$D$20=$F2),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1))^0)>0))
```

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I have just used initials to demonstrate the method.

[image]

[image]

I have formatted them using "#" to make the zeroes appear as blanks.

Comment: Would it be easier to build a script, maybe in python, that build this table? I want the process to be easily replicated when new authors are added.

Comment: Yes you are probably right, it's on the boundary of where you would use Excel formulas and where you would use a programming tool - VBA, Python or whichever one you are familiar with. I haven't addressed the question of how you would get the alphabetical list of individual distinct authors in the first place - have assumed in the way that @BruceWayne outlined - add,sort remove duplicates. If you wanted it to be dynamic that would be really challenging with Excel formulas and probably unwise unless others know different.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with any, I only know basic python but don't think is enough to develop a script for this. Do any of you know some tutorial that would help me develop this type of scrip?